# WebStorm autocompletion based on custom schema json files

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, autocomplete, webstorm, jsonschema

I have some json schema files describing the structure of my objects. Here is an example:

```
{
  "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$ref" : "#/$defs/AdaugaPersoana",
  "$defs" : {
    "AdaugaPersoana" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "numeComplet" : {
          "$ref" : "#/$defs/NumeComplet"
        },
        "stare" : {
          "$ref" : "#/$defs/Stare"
        }
      }
    },
    "NumeComplet" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "nume" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "prenume" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "factory()" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      },
      "required" : [ "nume" ]
    },
    "Stare" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "enum" : [ "ACTIVAT", "DEACTIVAT" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way that WebStorm can use this schema to autocomplete when using a JavaScript variable?

Example JS code:

```
/** @type AdaugaPersoana */
const someVar = {};

someVar.numeComplet.nume //this should be autocompleted
```

Comment: No, code completion based on JSON schemas only works in JSON files